# Task scheduling on multiple facilities - cumulative 'var opt error'

Tags: scheduling, constraint-programming, minizinc

I'm having trouble with an implementation of the following CP formulation (full formulation of the problem can be found [here (page 4/16)](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1150&context=tepper))

[image: CP formulation of the problem]

My implementation seems like code below, but I'm having struggle with following error: `MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: 'comulative(array[int] of var opt int,array[int] of var opt int,array[int] of var opt int,int)'`.

This is because array comprehension is affected by some var, in this case variable `x`.

Do you have any suggestions how to make `cumulative` constraint working with option variables or any possible workaround?

```
include "cumulative.mzn";
include "element.mzn";

int: numJ; % number of tasks
int: numI; % number of facilities

% Tasks
set of int: Tasks = 1..numJ;

% Facilities
set of int: Facilities = 1..numI;

% Max consumptions of facilities
array[Facilities] of int: C;

array[Tasks] of int: d; % due times
array[Tasks] of int: r; % release times
array[Facilities, Tasks] of int: c; % c[i,j] = consumption of task j at facility i
array[Facilities, Tasks] of int: p; % p[i,j] = processing time of task i at facility j
array[Facilities, Tasks] of int: F; % F[i,j] = fixed cost paid when task j is assigned to facility i

% start time's domain is an interval <0, maximum of due times>
array[Tasks] of var 0..max(d): s;

% assign task to a facility
% x[3] = 1 --> task 3 is assigned to facility 1
array[Tasks] of var 1..numI: x;

% something like a temporary processing time
% im not really sure about this
array[Tasks] of var 0..max(p): u;

constraint forall(j in Tasks)(
  element(
    x[j],
    [p[i,j] | i in Facilities],
    u[j]
  )
);


constraint forall(i in Facilities)(
  comulative(
    [s[j] | j in Tasks where x[j] == i],
    [p[i,j] | j in Tasks where x[j] == i],
    [c[i,j] | j in Tasks where x[j] == i],
    C[i]
  )
);




% A task cant start before its release time
constraint forall(j in Tasks)(s[j] >= r[j]);
% A task cant run longer than its due time
constraint forall(j in Tasks)(s[j] <= d[j] - u[j]);

% Minimize total cost
solve minimize sum(j in Tasks)(F[x[j],j]);

output [ "start: ", "\n", show(s), "\n", "facility: ", "\n" , show(x) , "\n"];
```

Simple data set:

```
C = [8, 8, 6, 5];

numJ = 12;
numI = 4;
r = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2];

d = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];

c = [|8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, |8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, |6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, |5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, |];

p = [|1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, |1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, |1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, |1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, |];

F = [|0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, |1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, |1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, |1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, |];
```

Comment: Just a note: the constraint is called "cumulative" (not "comulative"). However, changing to the correct name still yield the same type of error since the slices such as "[s[j] | j in Tasks where x[j] == i]" in cumulative is translated to "var opt int" (which is not supported in the cumulative constraint). I'll see if I can come up with some working model.

Comment: Another thing: Do you have a full example with the fixed parameters, e.g. numJ, numI, C, d, r, c, p, and F?

Comment: @hakank I've came up with a more straight forward solution which is not using cumulative nor element constraints but just mimics them. Going to answer this question by myself in a moment.

Comment: That's great. Note that there exists a cumulative that supports opts in the file "cumulative_opt.mzn" (so you should include this instead), but then both the slices of "p" and "s" must be without the "where x[j] == i", i.e..  "[p[i,j] | j in Tasks]".

Comment: I understand, I've found your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477453/constraint-programming-scheduling-with-multiple-workers?rq=1), thank you for this. My current solution is heavily inspired by yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you mentioned that you've found a solution, here's a version that use cumulative (opt version in "cumulative_opt.mzn").

```
include "globals.mzn"; % includes the file "cumulative_opt.mzn"
% ....

constraint forall(i in Facilities)(
    cumulative(
    % [s[j] | j in Tasks where x[j] == i], % original
    % [p[i,j] | j in Tasks where x[j] == i], % original
    % [c[i,j] | j in Tasks where x[j] == i], % original

    [s[j] | j in Tasks where x[j] == i],
    [p[i,j] | j in Tasks], % <-- no condition clause here
    [c[i,j] | j in Tasks], % <-- no condition clause here
    C[i]
 )
);
```

Comment: I spent like 7 hours searching for an answer how to get 'cumulative' constraint working with opt values and didnt notice the cumulative_opt at all. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: :-) I tend to browse the directory of global constraint files (*.mzn) in the directory "share/minizinc/std" to see if there is a corresponding constraint. And sometimes look at the listing at http://www.minizinc.org/2.0/doc-lib/doc.html .

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution and I hope it is easier to understand than the one with cumulative constraint.

```
array[Facilities, 0..max(d)] of var 0..max(C): facilityUsageAtTime;

constraint forall(i in Facilities) (
     forall(tt in 0..max(d)) (
        facilityUsageAtTime[i,tt] = sum(j in Tasks where x[j] == i /\ s[j] <= tt /\ tt < s[j] + p[x[j], j])(c[x[j],j]) /\
        facilityUsageAtTime[i,tt] <= C[i]
     )
);
```

It is heavily inspired by @hakank answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477453/constraint-programming-scheduling-with-multiple-workers?rq=1)